# element upward 100% when transform changed by 1px

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I am using css 3d transforms in my project. I am trying to apply a new transform on the containing element of several other elements. I am also trying to use getBoundingClientRect on one of its child elements. That container also has other elements in it. When the container has this value for the `transform` css property:

```
translateZ(1026px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(439.001px)
```

here's what `element.getBoundingClientRect().top` for that certain child element is: `77.953109741210944` according to chrome's developer tools but when I use the `elements` tab to change the `transform property to this:

```
translateZ(1027px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(439.001px)
```

here's what `element.getBoundingClientRect().top` is: `-75048.6484375` what would possibly cause this? I'm not posting any code because this occurs even when I modify the values through the console. And when I make the first `translateZ` something like 1000px, it is still about 77. Even when it is at 0 the top of the bounding rect is about 50-100 somewhere. But when it goes beyond 1026px, the elment seems to jump to top -80000 or so. Visually, however, the element look like it should and doesn't "jump" randomly at 1027px. Can somebody say a situation that might cause this?

in case it is a browser bug or something, I'm using chrome 32.0.1687.2 dev-m Aura

EDIT:

here is a jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/a6KxQ/2/

It'll generate a table of all `translateZ` values and the resulting `elt.getBoundingClientRect().top` values. The code's messy, but in the outputted table, if you look over it carefully, you'll find that, at some point, the top value will randomly jump far, far down. And then it'll quickly recover to come back to it's previous value. Weird.

The fiddle might take a long time to load.

Comment: Can you illustrate in a jsFiddle so we can better see and play with it.

Comment: I'm not sure, my app is really complex and other stuff might be affecting it, but I guess I can try.

Comment: i tried making a jsfiddle, but it works properly as expected, not showing the issue.

Comment: Then, the issue is probably related to something that you don't have in the jsFiddle which would be pretty hard for us to help with.  I think you'll need to work on isolating what else in your environment is leading to the problem.  Perhaps you can slowly add more things to your jsFiddle or diagnose what else in your code could be affecting it.

Comment: I looked at the [MDN doc for getBoundingClientRect().top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMClientRect) and it says `"Y-coordinate, relative to the viewport origin, of the top of the rectangle box."`  Any chance the viewport origin is getting shifted?

Comment: Because I'm modifying the transform directly through the console (not through javascript), I don't see how that is possible. But you would know better than me. Is there any way?

Comment: note that the entire element seems to "move out of the way", even though it looks like it is in the right place. e.g. when I use document.elementFromPoint on a point that looks like it is inside the element, it shows a different element which is behind it instead. Weird

Comment: Is the element in HTML layout or absolutely positioned?

Comment: @jfriend00 it is absolute. Also, I made a big mistake in the question. The CONTAINER of several elements is having its transform changed, and one of the CHILD elements of that container are having weirdbounding rects

Comment: the container and the child are both absolutely positioned

Comment: The reason I'm asking is if your change could be causing a layout change which causes objects to move around?  Just trying to guess what possibilities there are.

Comment: Another (possibly) important piece of information: in the bounding rect that I get after the "jump", the new bottom coordinate is the same as the previous top value

Comment: ok, the "jump" is actually the container moving upwards 100% as the new bottom is the previous top, and the container still has the same height. But it looks exactly the same as if it didn't jump/move at all!

Comment: Could your coordinate system be rotating 180 and that's why bottom is now top?

Comment: @jfriend00 i was able to reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle, see the link and info that I added to the question.

Comment: My guess would be `perspective` does something to the math.

Answer (score 8):

As you suspected, It has to do with the `perspective` of the viewpoint. By increasing of the value for the 1st `translateZ`, you are bringing the rectangle closer to you. Eventually it is so close, it has passed the point of the camera. From that point on, the shape, un-rotated, stood behind your eyes.

Then you did a `rotateX(-90deg)`. what happens there is the rectangle fell down forwards (towards the positive Z direction, but behind the camera.). Now, since the tunnel of the view is of a trapezoid shape, hence you get what we see in this screenshot:

[image]

With the rectangle behind the camera, as the it rotates, part of it is pivoted back into view.

So the getBoundingClientRect() is actually giving you the bottom of the shape's bound! Now that the shape is flipped, and it doesn't understand 3D.

I hope that made sense to you. I want to get to you first :) Ask me before down-voting, I can explain in more details.

so, it is by design. You probably want to restrict the `translateZ` value to be smaller than `perspective`.

EDIT:

sorry I have been busy. I meant to give a more detailed response. Thanks for whoever gave me the bounty.

[A updated demo](https://googledrive.com/host/0B3j1CaeS60S7V2VNVng1VnJHVE0/transformPuzzle.html)

Play around the numbers, you will make the following observations:

1. when `translateZ = perspective - 150px`, the bounding box is abnormally small and in wrong position
2. when `perspective - 150px < translateZ < perspective + 150px`, the bounding box is on the opposite side of where it should be, and the size is abnormally large
3. when `tranlateZ = perspective + 150px`, the bounding box is abnormally small again and higher in position in case 1)
4. the above is not affected by perspective-origin
5. 150px is half of the width/height of the square
6. when `tranlateZ > perspective + 150px`, the bounding box is normal again!

Why is that?

- in case 1) one of the edges just intersects with the plane that the camera/perspective is located.
- in case 2) the square intersects with the camera plane
- in case 3) the edge opposite  to the edge in case 1) now intersects with camera/perspective plane.
- in case 6) all of the square has passed the camera plane

The projection algorithm used to convert 3D coordinates to on screen 2D coodinates does not take into account of the fact that two corners are infront of the camera, and two other corners are behind, hence creating a wrong projection, and hence wrong size.

That was what I meant by "it doesn't understand 3D". That was vague as it can be I realize, Sorry. When all the shape is passed the camera plane, it works again.

Firefox, and Chrome both have this problem, but have different representations, numerically. Probably because different projections matrix are used. So I don't want to figure out what exactly went wrong. Fire a bug report to them :)

Realistically though, you might need to work around it.

Comment: Ok, this probably has the solution in it, but I don't exactly understand a lot of the things you're saying. For example, what exactly do you mean by `tunnel of view` and why is it trapezoid? What do you mean by `So the getBoundingClientRect() is actually giving you the bottom of the shape's bound!`? What do you mean "the bottom of the shape's bound"? Why does it mess up? Even if it's behind the camera, shouldn't it still be working properly if part of it comes back into view? Why `doesn't [it] understand 3d` anymore `Now that the shape is flipped`?

Comment: ok, I would like an explanation for how this works, but even if you don't provide one, I'll give you the bounty

Comment: @Markasoftware take a look at this demo i put together: [Link to Demo](https://googledrive.com/host/0B3j1CaeS60S7V2VNVng1VnJHVE0/Demo.html) The values of the BoundingClientRect after rotation is correct up to translateZ = 399px. It is wrong for 400px in a very interesting way, and for 401px and above your error occurs. The math is complicated since the perspective origin is changed, but the problem is clearly with the perspective. You can avoid the error by limiting the value of translateZ. It is late at night. I will try to write more tmr.

Comment: Sorry, but you don't really explain why the bounding rect is off. It can't be "not understanding 3d anymore", because it renders it still in the right place. The bounty requirements clearly said: `I don't want a "hacky" way to fix this` so far, this doesn't fit that. It provides an explanation which doesn't really make sense, and all it says is to keep the translateZ smaller than the perspective. But my application NEEDS the translateZ to be greater than the perspective. That's how it's supposed to work. So sorry, without modification, this answer is not going to get the bounty.

Comment: Ok, finally decided to look at this again and see if I can understand it properly this time...I think I've got it. So basically, it doesn't like partially visible shapes, so it doesn't really know what to do in those situations. Although that does kind've explain what's going on, your answer doesn't really have any solution, so I'm not going to accept it yet.

Comment: hey @Markasoftware, it has been a while. I still suggest you to use with the demo in the original answer. It will help you find the exact condition where the error occurs. As far as I can remember It is math problem that has to do with getting the size of a 2D project of 3D object. The 3D object's original lower edge is now higher then its original upper edge. However the getBoundingClientRect still tries to get the difference between the upper and lower edges. Sorry I don't have a solution except review what are you trying to do, and maybe find another way to calculate the size of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to explain it, and it could be off base, but when you comment out the the `perspective` css you get the same values down the whole table. I'm not sure what `perspective` does to the math...

```
#main3DWrapper{
  /*
  -webkit-perspective: 1500px;
  -moz-perspective: 1500px;
  perspective:1500px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 1%;
  perspective-origin:50% 1%;
  */
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0,0);
  transform:translate3d(0,0,0,0);
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: -121.96603393554688px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 409.5150146484375px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also, why are you setting the `translateZ()` value twice in the `js`?

```
container.style.webkitTransform='translateZ('+dist+'px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(429.001px)';
container.style.transform='translateZ('+dist+'px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(429.001px)';
```

Shouldn't is just be?:

```
container.style.webkitTransform='translateZ('+dist+'px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg)';
container.style.transform='translateZ('+dist+'px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg)';
```

Comment: This is not the answer I was looking for. First off, `perspective` is necessary for most things in css 3D transforms. To make a 3d effect, you need the `perspective`. Additionally, I also want to use `perspective-origin` to get the right viewing angle. Yes, it does something to the math, but it's supposed to. Secondly, I WANT the values to change in the table, but I want them to keep increasing instead of randomly jumping down. Finally, I'm using two `translateZ`s because translating after rotation translates it a different direction, even though it still says `Z`. -1, this answers misses lots